# Formula to find the cell in column C where a value in column A = a value in column E

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

[image: I manually typed the info in Column D but that's how I want the answers to populate]I'm trying to create a formula in a google sheet to find the value in the C column where the value in the A column is equal to the value in the E column.

E.g. Column E = 1 in Row 9-16 and Column A = 1 in row 2, therefore, show what's in Column C row 2

Column E = 2 in Row 17-24 and Column A = 2 in row 3, therefore, show what's in Column C row 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### EDIT

(following OP's edited question)

Please use the following in cell `D2`:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E2:E,$A$2:$C,3,0)))
```

[image]

---

#### Original answer

Please use the following formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A13=E2:E13,C2:C13,""))
```

(of course you can adjust the ranges to your liking)

If on the other hand need to show the results as in your example, use this one:

```
=VLOOKUP(E16,A2:C,3,0)
```

Functions used:

- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)
- `IFERROR`

Comment: Hey @marikamitsos, I've added a ss of how I want it to look. The formula would go into Column D

Comment: Please have a look at the updated formula.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you soooo much! I've been wrecking my brain on this for days!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: One last question, for the formula I have in Cell E2, how to I get it copied to all the cells in the entire column (e.g. 900'000 cells) instead of dragging it down?

Comment: Okay, I've just posted it https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/142385/how-do-i-get-a-formula-copied-to-all-the-cells-below-it-in-the-entire-column-e

Comment: Hey marikamitsos, I've just posted another question here, https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/142403/how-do-i-populate-cells-with-formulas-from-one-google-sheet-into-another-while! Can you please check it when you get a chance please? Thanks!