# How do I get a formula copied to all cells below it in the entire column and increment by x instead of manually dragging it down to eternity?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

If in Cell `A2` I have the formula,

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),1)=0,A2+1,A2)
```

how do I get it copied to all the cells below in the entire column (e.g. 900'000 cells) instead of manually dragging it down to eternity?

Comment: Your first formula trigger a an infinite loop (Iterative calculation) so 'im not sure this `=ArrayFormula(IF(MOD(ROW(),1)=0,A2:A10+1,A2:A10))` can solve the problem. Second formula, i'm not sure what you're looking for, can you explain a bit more ?

Comment: This is my original question, so you have an idea of what I'm looking to achieve. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/142367/formula-to-find-the-cell-in-column-c-where-a-value-in-column-a-a-value-in-colu#142370

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using the following arrayformula in cell `E2`:

```
=ArrayFormula(INT((ROW(A2:A)-1)/9))
```

[image]

#### How the formula works:

**First of all you need to make sure you place it in the correct row**. That is if your range starts at the second row (like `E2-E`) row you place it in the second row. As you notice in the given formula the column is `A`. That is to show you that **the column makes no difference**. It could be any column. **It is the row that is important**.

Then we fix the step which is one above the one we want. In this case in order **to have 8 repetitions, we divide by 9**.

Finally, we can control the starting number by adding a number in the last part of the formula.In this case **we start from zero so we add nothing**.
But in columns `B` and `C` we start from 1 and 2 so we use:

in column `B`

```
=ArrayFormula(INT((ROW(B2:B)-1)/9)+1)
```

and in column `C`

```
=ArrayFormula(INT((ROW(C2:C)-1)/9)+2)
```

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`INT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093490)
- [`ROW`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316)

Comment: Please remember that you can also [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) an answer so others can benefit as well.